# How to make utility class (library) both working with CDI @Inject and new instance in Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, shared-libraries, jboss7.x, cdi

We are migrating current project to Java EE 6 (maybe 7 later) and learning what happened in Java EE world in last 5 years along the way. We have organizational and logical issue to tackle now.

We created separate utility library which will handle l10n, dates, currency conversions and so on. This library (jar) will be on our local maven repository (nexus) and other projects and modules will use it if needed.

Part of our team members liked (new) managed way of doing things:

```
@Inject
DateFormatter df;
```

And if we put in our library class `@Singleton` we do not have to write `static` hundreds of times.

BUT, other part of the team thinks that old school way is the way yo do it:

```
...
DateFormatter df = new DateFormatter();
String localizedDate = df.localize('2013-10-01')
...
```

Mostly because it seems unnatural to `@Inject` things like Regex, string utils and similar utility classes which are not needed in whole service class, only in some method.

And, of course, it seems that you can do both, if you try to `@Inject` same class which has been already initiated somewhere else via `new` , you get `NullPointerException` in JBOSS AS 7.

So, how should we do it ?
Is there any way to make it work  with both ways, if not, which you would recommend ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want to continue using it in the old way (instantiating, allowing application to manage the instances), leave it as is.

For those wanting to use the new way, add a producer layer on top of your JAR file.  This can be its own JAR file, and simply provides products for these various utility classes.  Now the trade off is that both sides need to agree to stop using static methods, or if they want to continue using statics those need to exist in its own JAR, the same way the CDI add on works.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you to go with the first option, only with exception that I would make that class `@ApplicationScoped` instead of `@Singleton` (in terms of CDI, EJB singleton is something different with more capabilities like locking). There is virtually no difference but new CDI spec doesn't even mention CDI `@Singleton` scope so I guess it will get deprecated in favor of `@ApplicationScoped`.

With this, you don't have to create new instance of your utility class all the time (or import static methods) but there will be one instance per application so it will give better you performance. Also, your utility class can benefit from injecting other components to it, interceptors and other CDI stuff. Now you know probably why can't you use both ways, if you try to call `new DateFormatter()`, bean won't be container managed anymore (so you will end up with more instances in your app), it will just mess up things so stick with it the first solution and you will be fine:)